# Google Script XML Parsing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I am parsing the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://www.sportsbook.ag/rss/nfl-football" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>Sportsbook.com Live Football Betting Odds RSS Feed</title>
    <link>https://www.sportsbook.ag/rss/nfl-football</link>
    <description>Football Betting Feed</description>
    <language>en</language>
          <item>
    <title>Dallas Cowboys @ Minnesota Vikings</title>
    <link>http://www.sportsbook.ag/livesports/nfl</link>
    <description>&lt;strong&gt;12-1-16 8:25 PM&lt;/strong&gt;
Bet on Dallas Cowboys &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116PSA]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|PSA|1|100|115|-7|-115&quot;&gt;-3.5 (-115)&lt;/a&gt;
Money:&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116MLA]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|MLA|1|100|180|0|-180&quot;&gt;-180&lt;/a&gt;
or Minnesota Vikings &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;/selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116PSH]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|PSH|1|100|105|7|-105&quot;&gt;3.5 (-105)&lt;/a&gt;
Money:&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116MLA]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|MLA|1|100|180|0|-180&quot;&gt;+157&lt;/a&gt;.
Totals: &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116TLO]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|TLO|1|100|110|89|-110&quot;&gt;Over 44.5 (-110)&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;amp;action=addBet&amp;amp;betTypeId=80&amp;amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116TLU]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|TLU|1|100|110|89|-110&quot;&gt;Under 44.5 (-110)&lt;/a&gt;</description>
     <pubDate>12-1-16 8:25 PM</pubDate>
 <dc:creator />
 <guid isPermaLink="false" />
  </item>
```

with the following Google Apps Script:

```
function stugass() {
  var live = new Array();
  var url = "https://www.sportsbook.ag/rss/nfl-football";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var games = document.getRootElement().getChild('channel').getChildren('item');
  if(document == null) {
    document.getRootElement().getChild('channel').getChildren('item');
  }
  for (var i=0; i < games.length-1; i++) {
    vegas = [];
    var game = games[i];
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('title'));
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('link'));
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('description'));


    live.push(vegas);
    }
    return live;
 }
```

How do I split up the "BLOB" portion of the 'description' tag into multiple cells in the Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious how far you want to split that field, but here is one way to do it, using `split` string method with regex argument that splits by HTML tags found in that description. The array returned by this method is filtered to eliminate any whitespace-only pieces.

```
var description = game.getChildText('description').split(/<\/?strong>|<a href="|">[^<]*<\/a>/);
vegas = vegas.concat(description.filter(function (a) {return a.trim().length;}));
live.push(vegas);
```

Output looks like

```
12-1-16 8:25 PM  |   Bet on Dallas Cowboys   |  https://www.sportsbook.ag/sbk/sportsbook4/www.sportsbook.ag/updatecart5.cgi?sportTypeId=203&amp;action=addBet&amp;betTypeId=80&amp;selection[Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116PSA]=Foot-Dalla-Minne-120116|PSA|1|100|105|-7|-105   |  ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I have been using what you gave me to get a different output.  But How can I get there results with the content inside the <a> tag... For instance <a href="....dont need this..."> Need This</a>??

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it simple like this:

```
function stugass() {
  var live = new Array();
  var url = "https://www.sportsbook.ag/rss/nfl-football";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var games = document.getRootElement().getChild('channel').getChildren('item');
  if(document == null) {
    document.getRootElement().getChild('channel').getChildren('item');
  }
  for (var i=0; i < games.length-1; i++) {
    vegas = [];
    var game = games[i];
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('title'));
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('link'));
    vegas.push(game.getChildText('description').replace(/<a href=\S+\">|<\S+>/g,''));


    live.push(vegas);
    }
    return live;
 }
```

The output looks like this:

[image]